# How to remove duplicates from an oracle query with multiple range values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to remove duplicates in a SQL query and I keep getting duplicates
Heres the code I have so far

```
SELECT    e1.LName, w1.PNo, e2.LName, w2.PNo, p.Plocation
FROM      Employee e1, Employee e2, Works_On w1, Works_On w2, Project p
WHERE     e1.SSN = w1.ESSN        AND
          e2.SSN = w2.ESSN        AND
          e1.SSN != e2.SSN        AND
          w1.PNo = w2.PNo         AND
          w1.Pno = p.PNumber      AND
          p.PLocation = 'Houston'
ORDER BY  e1.LName
```

And this is the output

```
LNAME   PNO LNAME   PNO PLOCATION
Borg    20  Wong    20  Houston
Borg    20  Wallace 20  Houston
Narayan 3   Wong    3   Houston
Wallace 20  Wong    20  Houston
Wallace 20  Borg    20  Houston
Wong    20  Borg    20  Houston
Wong    3   Narayan 3   Houston
Wong    20  Wallace 20  Houston
```

As you can see, there are certain rows with duplicates where the last names are flipped. I am not sure how I am supposed to remove those rows

Edit:
Instead of putting e1.SSN != e2.SSN, I changed it to e1.SSN > e2.SSN and got the result I wanted
and I get this result now

```
LNAME   PNO LNAME   PNO PLOCATION
Borg    20  Wallace 20  Houston
Wong    20  Wallace 20  Houston
Wong    3   Narayan 3   Houston
Wong    20  Borg    20  Houston
```

Comment: You want all pairs removed or just "half"?

Comment: Please put some rows from your source table here.

Comment: probably you don't need self join here. you can do it with only join like  select e.LName, w.PNO, p.Plocation FROM Employee e JOIN Works_On w ON e.SSN = w.ESSN JOIN Project P ON w.PNO = P.PNumber and P.Plocation ='Houston' order by e.LName

Comment: What's the point of the query? To come up with all the ways in which to arrange pairs of people who are on a team at a project at Houston? It just seems like an odd requirement. Why not instead find a list of employees assigned to each such project that is at Houston? Mixing them up into all possible pairs without overlap doesn't seem like it would serve any purpose.

Comment: The point of my query is For projects located in Houston: Find pairs of last names such that the two employees in the pair work on the same project. Remove duplicates. Sort the result by the lname in the left column in the result.

Comment: I understand what you want I just don't understand why it would ever be an actual business need. In any case, can you post the table's data?

Comment: It's a HW assignment so it doesn't have to make sense. I did make an edit to how I came to my solution